# asp mvc session variables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Need to store some auth information of client on server, to share between 2 pages.
Dont matter how, session, cookie, tempdata, i tried everything, and nothing works, for exampe:

```
public ActionResult CheckIn(string pass)
    {
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"] == pass)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Add("admin", "yes");
        }
        return View();
    } 
public ActionResult Helper() {
        if (HttpContext.Session["admin"] != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session["admin"].ToString() == "yes")
                return PartialView("InitConfig");
            else
                return PartialView("StationLogics");
        }
        else
            return PartialView("StationLogics");
    }
```

and i get always null in session in helper method. what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead ?

ps. doing that you do is actually not good desing you should reconsider it in your application.

Comment: and i dont have HttpContext.Current

Comment: it depends what you want to do :), using session for such trivial task is bad. whole mvc framework created to make it more correct. you have to have action that would authicate user and redirect him base on his role. each action could include attbite which role it handles. you should be more familar with asp.net membership

Comment: thx. so, i want to call controller, with diffrent roles, have u any links about it?

Comment: this might be good for start : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all those `if` conditions are met? Try with a simple example:

```
public ActionResult CheckIn()
{
    Session["foo"] = "bar";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Helper() 
{
    var foo = Session["foo"]; 
    if (foo == null)        
    {
        // this won't be null if you called the CheckIn method first
    }
    return View();
}
```

Call the `CheckIn` action first to store a value in the session and then call the `Helper` action. Unless you have disabled session for this ASP.NET application or cookies in your browser you should get correct value.

Comment: i;m sure, looking by debugger. how can i check enbled or disabled session in my app?

Comment: And what about cookies? Are they enabled in your browser?